# Unity 3D-Cannot add Physic Material to a model imported from Blender?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, blender, 3d-model

I have made a simple Blender model and imported the .blend file into unity,I want to add `Physic Material` to it but my cursor was showing cancel sign,I cannot drag the texture to it.

Please help!

See the images:

I want to add physics to the `Donut` component (the `Game.blend` in the assets).

[This is my unity window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiANQ.png)

Expanding the Donut component will appear `Torus` and `Torus.001`

[Expanded the Donut component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvUWO.png)

My donut also have a rigid component that I accidentally clicked,but I didn't add any scripts into it.

Comment: What is a Physic Texture?  Did you mean Physics Material?  Or just Texture?

Comment: Oops,I made a mistake,It should be "Physic Material"

Comment: The physics material gets assigned to the collider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution

1. Add a `collider` component in the game object inspector
2. Click on the `None` material and replace it by the `Physic Material` folder.